# Datagridview save changes to Database vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, save

Hello i've a databse that i load to Datagridview in vb.net application.
it loads fine, however when i try to save the date it doesn't work.
here is the code

```
    Private myConString As String
Private con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Private Dadapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Private DSet As DataSet
Private DSet2 As DataSet
Private ConCMD As OleDb.OleDbCommand

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=e:\Database31.accdb"
    con.ConnectionString = myConString
    con.Open()
    Dadapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Table1", con)
    DSet = New DataSet
    Dadapter.Fill(DSet, "Table1")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DSet.Tables("Table1")
    con.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    con.Open()
    Dadapter.Update(DSet, "Table1")
    DSet.AcceptChanges()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows.
what am i supposed to do?

the accessdatabase 3 colmuns and ID is primary key
ID  Field1  Field2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you must define an [`InsertCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.insertcommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for you `DataAdapter`

Side-note: The line `DSet.AcceptChanges()` is redundant since the previous line `Dadapter.Update` will call `AcceptChanges` implicitely.

You should use `using-statement` for anything  implementing `IDisposable` like a Connection. That would call `Dispose`(which closes the connection) implicitely even in case of an exception.

So replace:

```
con.Open()
Dadapter.Update(DSet, "Table1")
DSet.AcceptChanges()
con.Close()
```

with

```
Using con =  New OleDbConnection(myConString)
    con .Open()
    Dadapter.Update(DSet, "Table1")
End Using
```

Comment: thanks, but still what is an insert command?!my database has only 3 fields  ID Field1 Field2..so how should my insert command look like?

Comment: Edited my answer to provide the msdn link for [OleDbDataAdapter.InsertCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.insertcommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). There's an example of an sql `INSERT` statement.

Comment: great..now suppose i filled the datagrid view 2000 new values with a loop for different fields..and i want to save this what is the best approach to do this? the inserting should be during the loop not after the loop?

Comment: @user1492051: Have a look at this sample code which shows how to bind a DataGridView to an Access database and how to select,update,delete and insert: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148532-using-datagridview-with-access/

Comment: I would also add `Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(Dadapter)` before the `.Update` method to prevent this error: "Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows"

Answer (score 0):

You need to read back the dataset from the datagrid

```
con.Open()
DSet = DataGridView1.DataSource  '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Dadapter.Update(DSet, "Table1")
DSet.AcceptChanges()
con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

My VB.NET code for the 4 type of databases (update information from DataGridView to Database)

```
Private Sub sqldb_savedata()
    Dim connectionString As String = "Server='" & sql_server & "';Database='" & sql_database & "';User Id='" & sql_user & "';Password='" & sql_pass & "'"
    Dim sqlCon = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    If (sqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then sqlCon.Open()
    Dim SQLAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM clinics", sqlCon)
    Dim SQLDataSet As New DataSet
    Dim myTable = DataGridViewClinic.DataSource
    Dim cmdbuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(SQLAdapter)
    SQLAdapter.Update(myTable, "clinics")
    MsgBox("Updated!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "")
End Sub

Private Sub mysqldb_savedata()
    Dim connectionString As String = "Server='" & mysql_server & "';Database='" & mysql_database & "';User Id='" & mysql_user & "';Password='" & mysql_pass & "'"
    Dim sqlCon = New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    If (sqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then sqlCon.Open()
    Dim SQLAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM clinics", sqlCon)
    Dim SQLDataSet As New DataSet
    Dim myTable = DataGridViewClinic.DataSource
    Dim cmdbuilder As New MySqlCommandBuilder(SQLAdapter)
    SQLAdapter.Update(myTable, "clinics")
    MsgBox("Updated!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "")
End Sub

Private Sub firebirddb_savedata()
    Dim connectionString As String = "Database='" & firebird_server & "';User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Dialect=3;ServerType=1"
    Dim sqlCon = New FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection(connectionString)
    If (sqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then sqlCon.Open()
    Dim SQLAdapter = New FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM clinics", sqlCon)
    Dim SQLDataSet As New DataSet
    Dim myTable = DataGridViewClinic.DataSource
    Dim cmdbuilder As New FirebirdClient.FbCommandBuilder(SQLAdapter)
    SQLAdapter.Update(myTable, "clinics")
    MsgBox("Updated!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "")
End Sub

 Private Sub localdb_savedata()
    DBconn = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf")
    If (DBconn.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then DBconn.Open()
    Dim SQLAdapter = New SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM clinics", DBconn)
    Dim SQLDataSet As New DataSet
    Dim myTable = DataGridViewClinic.DataSource
    Dim cmdbuilder As New SqlCeCommandBuilder(SQLAdapter)
    SQLAdapter.Update(myTable, "clinics")
    MsgBox("Updated!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "")
End Sub
```