# Datagridview duplicate values on update

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

So here is the deal.. I have a vb app that is for budget expenses. I have a datagridview in budget form showing only values from the opened budget on the budgets form.

I have this textbox that onchange loads the materials (from table materials)
All the data is inserted and updated in database.

But when i try to update my datagridview, it instead of just adding the new row, it adds the whole table again and keeps the old values instead of updating.

I've been trying to delete the datagrid values and rebind the datasource but it keeps adding instead of updating.

```
ArtigorcamentoDataGridView.DataSource = Nothing
ArtigorcamentoDataGridView.Rows.Clear()

daartorc.Fill(Me.BigbuilderDataSet.artigorcamento)
ArtigorcamentoDataGridView.DataSource = Me.BigbuilderDataSet.artigorcamento
```

I've also tryed to `daartorc.update(Me.BigbuilderDataSet.artigorcamento)` instead of fill but it does nothing...

Comment: do you added ArtigorcamentoDataGridView.DataBind(); after applying datasource ?

Comment: no, i'l give a feedback in a minute

Comment: 'DataBind' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'.

Comment: Have you searched how to actually do this, or are you just trying random things?

Comment: yes i'v been looking for info but now this databind, never used it, and i dont know how to use it...

Comment: oh yes you have desktop application right ? it is applicable to web application.

Comment: Can you checked Me.BigbuilderDataSet.artigorcamento dataset,It has proper data or not?

Comment: It would benefit you to search for these things before asking questions, because your answer probably exists somewhere. Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379615/datagridview-save-changes-to-database-vb-net)

Comment: As a direct comment to the code you posted: You're filling a DataTable inside a DataSet with data. Then, you're assigning that as the data source of your DataGridView. I see no code that deals with updating a datagridview.

Comment: im using a data adapter that is daartorc... the source of the datagridview is in the designer,you know, this is from school, im not an expert in vb but this is a whole new area, i've been looking for this since 10 am, and i cant make it work, it just repeats all data, my dataset is ok it haves the proper data, but in the datagridview it repeats, but on the form load it loads ok