# insert data to datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how do i insert money row and colomns to datagridview?
like [i went to insert to datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPCsL.png) this
is my code:

```
Private Sub btnSimpan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSimpan.Click
    Call konek()
    Dim simpan As String
    Dim hasil As Integer

    simpan = ("INSERT INTO T_Penjadwalan(Kode_Penjadwalan,Kelas,Kode_Jam,Jam_Mulai,Jam_Selesai,Senin,Selasa,Rabu,Kamis,Jumat,Sabtu) VALUES ('" & TBPENJADWALAN.Text & "','" & CBKelas.Text &
             "','" & KJ1.Text & "','" & KJ2.Text & "','" & KJ3.Text & "','" & KJ4.Text & "','" & KJ5.Text & "','" & KJ6.Text & "','" & KJ7.Text & "','" & KJ8.Text & "','" & KJ9.Text &
             "','" & JM1.Text & "','" & JM2.Text & "','" & JM3.Text & "','" & JM4.Text & "','" & JM5.Text & "','" & JM6.Text & "','" & JM7.Text & "','" & JM8.Text & "','" & JM9.Text &
             "','" & JS1.Text & "','" & JS2.Text & "','" & JS3.Text & "','" & JS4.Text & "','" & JS5.Text & "','" & JS6.Text & "','" & JS7.Text & "','" & JS8.Text & "','" & JS9.Text &
             "','" & Senin1.Text & "','" & Senin2.Text & "','" & Senin3.Text & "','" & Senin4.Text & "','" & Senin5.Text & "','" & Senin6.Text & "','" & Senin7.Text &
             "','" & Selasa1.Text & "','" & Selasa2.Text & "','" & Selasa3.Text & "','" & Selasa4.Text & "','" & Selasa5.Text & "','" & Selasa6.Text & "','" & Selasa7.Text &
             "','" & Rabu1.Text & "','" & Rabu2.Text & "','" & Rabu3.Text & "','" & Rabu4.Text & "','" & Rabu5.Text & "','" & Rabu6.Text & "','" & Rabu7.Text &
             "','" & Kamis1.Text & "','" & Kamis2.Text & "','" & Kamis3.Text & "','" & Kamis4.Text & "','" & Kamis5.Text & "','" & Kamis6.Text & "','" & Kamis7.Text &
             "','" & Jumat1.Text & "','" & Jumat2.Text & "','" & Jumat3.Text & "','" & Jumat4.Text & "','" & Jumat5.Text & "','" & Jumat6.Text & "','" & Jumat7.Text &
             "','" & Sabtu1.Text & "','" & Sabtu2.Text & "','" & Sabtu3.Text & "','" & Sabtu4.Text & "','" & Sabtu5.Text & "','" & Sabtu6.Text & "','" & Sabtu7.Text & "')")
    Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand(simpan, conn)
        hasil = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If hasil > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data Tersimpan", "Sukses", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Call tampilgridpenjadwalan()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Failed : " & ex.Message, "Gagal", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub}
```

Comment: You have way more values than you have fields. You need to switch this over to using parameters and fix the insert statement. Then determine if you're really asking how to insert this into a database because that is what this code seems to be attempting to do (somewhat). A DataGridView is a GUI interface of rows and columns that allows viewing and editing of data in a table-like layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datagridview save changes to Database vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379615/datagridview-save-changes-to-database-vb-net)

Comment: can you show me how the code
because i don't now

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as others have said, it is better to use parameters when executing SQL queries in VB.NET. It has many benefits and it's fairly simple.

Taking a snippet of your insert query as an example, instead of defining the first value clause as `'" & TBPENJADWALAN.Text & "'` the first value might be `@TBPENJADWALAN`.

The string from `TBPENJADWALAN.Text` is then passed to `@TBPENJADWALAN` using the following code:

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@TBPENJADWALAN", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TBPENJADWALAN.Text`

> *OleDbType.VarChar = Type of data you're storing*
>
> *50 = Size of your field*

So instead of your code as follows...

```
simpan = ("INSERT INTO T_Penjadwalan(Kode_Penjadwalan) VALUES ('" & TBPENJADWALAN.Text & "')
```

...it would be:

```
simpan = ("INSERT INTO T_Penjadwalan(Kode_Penjadwalan) VALUES (@TBPENJADWALAN)")

cmd.Parameters.Add("@TBPENJADWALAN", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TBPENJADWALAN.Text
```

It's much cleaner and more secure. You can take that example and change the rest of your insert query.

---

In terms of your original question about inserting data to a `DataGridView`, in my experience, it's best to create a `DataSet` and `Adapter` to fill it. Try this:

```
Dim adapter As SQLDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
adapter = New SQLDataAdapter(simpan, cmd)
adapter.Fill(ds)
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Comment: Since the OP is using an SqlCommand I would guess he is using a SQL Server so this would be SqlDbType.